# Windows Batch: Split file based on keyword using native commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file test.txt that looks something like this:

```
HEADER Field# 1
HDR-ADDL1 Field# 1 Field# 2
DETAIL Field# 1 Field#2
HEADER Field# 1
HDR-ADDL1 Field# 1 Field# 2
HDR-ADDL2 Field# 1 Field# 2 Field# 3
DETAIL Field# 1 Field#2
HEADER Field# 1
HDR-ADDL1 Field# 1 Field# 2
DETAIL Field# 1 Field#2
```

I would like to split the file based on the keyword: HEADER. So for the above example, it should create 3 files: test_1.txt, test_2.txt and test_3.txt as follows:

test_1.txt

```
HEADER Field# 1
HDR-ADDL1 Field# 1 Field# 2
DETAIL Field# 1 Field#2
```

test_2.txt

```
HEADER Field# 1
HDR-ADDL1 Field# 1 Field# 2
HDR-ADDL2 Field# 1 Field# 2 Field# 3
DETAIL Field# 1 Field#2
```

test_3.txt

```
HEADER Field# 1
HDR-ADDL1 Field# 1 Field# 2
DETAIL Field# 1 Field#2
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this using native Windows batch commands?

Thanks!

Comment: What attempts of your own have you made? You have been here for quite some time, so I am sure you are aware that code requests are off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q64520741.txt"
set /a filecount=0

FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 for /f %%b in ("%%a") do if /i "%%b"=="header" set /a filecount+=1
 echo %%a>>"%destdir%\test_!filecount!.txt"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q64520741.txt` containing your data for my testing.

I've assumed that there are no `test_*.txt` files in the destination directory.

Having set the source and destination directories and the data filename, we start a counter.

Read each line of the file to `%%a`. `usebackq` tells batch that the filename-to-be-read is quoted. `delims=` sets `no delimiter` so the entire line is assigned to `%%a`.

The inner `for /f` sets `%%b` to the first character-string on the line (default), delimited by <kbd>Space</kbd> (default; also `,`, `;` and <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Test `%%b` for string-equivalence (`/i` says "case-insensitive") and if the first word on the line matches, increment the `filecount`.

Then append the line in `%%a` to the filename constructed from the string `test_` and the *current* value of `filecount` `.txt`.

The reason for quoting the filenames is to accommodate file/pathnames that contain spaces (etc.)

Answer (score -5):

Following script should work and should be selfexplaining

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & set cnt=
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (header.txt) do (
            echo %%~a | findstr HEADER >NUL
            if not errorlevel 1 (
                        set /a cnt=!cnt!+1
                        )
            echo %%~a>>text_!cnt!.txt  
            )
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a self-explanatory batch script. Don't use it as an excuse to justify posting a code-only answer.

Comment: There is a self-explaining batch script, look at it one more time and you will see. thnx

Comment: Could you explain what the two ampersands in the first line mean? Why does this not need doublequotes, like the other answer? What happens if `test.txt` or in your case, `header.txt`, has one or more spaces or poison characters in its actual name/path? Why are you using both `tokens=*` and `delims=`? Can you explain why you're using `!cnt!` in your `set /a` command? Could you please explain how `echo %%~a>>text_!cnt!.txt` works, because the resulting text files seem to have some content missing?

Comment: Compo, you?? Well known batch expert asking such questions? I do not believe my eyes. But OK, lets play a game: Ampersands do command chaining. Cant talk about the other answers. If special characters in filename, than file owner will rename it. It is much easier solution than do anythig else. He asked solution for one single file.Tokens may be redundant in this case. Do not understand !cnt! set /a question. echo append lines of original file into the specific output file.

Comment: @Compo did not ask the questions because he does not understand what you are doing, he is asking you the questions because it does not make sense and simply wants you to understand the problems. Why do you want to chain the commands, when you are in a batch file and not a one liner from `cmd`? the `set /a` relates to the correct method being `set /a cnt+=1` and there is absolutely no need to parenthesize the `if` block because there are no `else` statements. and lastly, your `echo %%~a>>text_!cnt!.txt` is dangerous, see what happens if your line has an numeric ending when redirecting to file.

Comment: Then as for your comment. _"There is a self-explaining batch script, look at it one more time and you will see"_ No, absolutely not. If the code was self explanatory, there would have been no reason for the OP to even ask a question here, he/she would simply understand it as the code is "self explanatory"

Comment: Ah so, Compo want to teach me in batch files writing. Lovely from him, isnt it? Compo should teach the OP, he present problem to solve. Not me.